# Sphinx Autodoc and NumpyDoc

Tags: numpy, python-sphinx, autodoc, numpydoc

despite reading [this tutorial](http://codeandchaos.wordpress.com/2012/07/30/sphinx-autodoc-tutorial-for-dummies/), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206334/sphinx-autosummary-toctree-contains-reference-to-nonexisting-document-warnings) and the [numpy docstring standard](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/HOWTO_DOCUMENT.rst.txt#docstring-standard), I'm unable to get sphinx autodoc to play nicely with numpy docstrings.

In my `conf.py` I have:

```
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc', 'numpydoc']
```

and in my doc file I have:

```
 .. automodule:: python_file

 .. autoclass:: PythonClass
   :members:
```

where `python_file.py` has:

```
class PythonClass(object):
    def do_stuff(x):
        """
        This does good stuff.

        Here are the details about the good stuff it does.

        Parameters
        ----------
        x : int
            An integer which has amazing things done to it

        Returns
        -------
        y : int
            Some other thing
        """
        return x + 1
```

When I run `make html` I get `ERROR: Unknown directive type "autosummary"`. When I add `autosummary` to my `extensions` thus:

```
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc', 'numpydoc', 'sphinx.ext.autosummary']
```

I get:

```
WARNING: toctree references unknown document u'docs/python_file.PythonClass.do_stuff'
```

As recommended by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206334/sphinx-autosummary-toctree-contains-reference-to-nonexisting-document-warnings), I add `numpydoc_show_class_members = False` to my `conf.py`.

Now I can run `make html` without errors, but the `Parameters` and `Returns` sections are not interpreted as being numpydoc sections.

Is there a way out of this mess?

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the whole previous `html` output. Then regenerate the docs.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Same issue exists after deleting it and rerunning. Any other ideas?