# Problems with Sphinx documenting class methods

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm trying use Sphinx to document a Python package I'm building, and everything was working fine until I added some classes. I'll just provide the full set of warnings so as not to leave out something relevant:

```
Running Sphinx v1.2.3
loading pickled environment... done
building [html]: targets for 1 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 0 added, 1 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] opt.core                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
/Users/marshallfarrier/Workspace/pynance/doc/source/opt.core.rst:44: WARNING: toctree references unknown document 'pynance.opt.core.Options.exps'
/Users/marshallfarrier/Workspace/pynance/doc/source/opt.core.rst:44: WARNING: toctree references unknown document 'pynance.opt.core.Options.info'
/Users/marshallfarrier/Workspace/pynance/doc/source/opt.core.rst:44: WARNING: toctree references unknown document 'pynance.opt.core.Options.quotetime'
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [100%] opt.core                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
None:None: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document 'pynance.opt.core.Options.exps'
None:None: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document 'pynance.opt.core.Options.info'
None:None: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document 'pynance.opt.core.Options.quotetime'
None:None: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document 'pynance.opt.price.Price.exps'
None:None: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document 'pynance.opt.price.Price.get'
None:None: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document 'pynance.opt.price.Price.metrics'
None:None: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document 'pynance.opt.price.Price.strikes'
None:None: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document 'pynance.opt.spread.core.Spread.cal'
None:None: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document 'pynance.opt.spread.multi.Multi.dblcal'
None:None: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document 'pynance.opt.spread.multi.Multi.diagbtrfly'
None:None: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document 'pynance.opt.spread.vert.Vertical.straddle'
None:None: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document 'pynance.opt.core.Options.exps'
None:None: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document 'pynance.opt.core.Options.info'
None:None: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document 'pynance.opt.core.Options.quotetime'
None:None: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document 'pynance.opt.price.Price.exps'
None:None: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document 'pynance.opt.price.Price.get'
None:None: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document 'pynance.opt.price.Price.metrics'
None:None: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document 'pynance.opt.price.Price.strikes'
None:None: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document 'pynance.opt.spread.core.Spread.cal'
None:None: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document 'pynance.opt.spread.multi.Multi.dblcal'
None:None: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document 'pynance.opt.spread.multi.Multi.diagbtrfly'
None:None: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document 'pynance.opt.spread.vert.Vertical.straddle'
<autosummary>:None: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document 'pynance.opt.core.Options.exps'
<autosummary>:None: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document 'pynance.opt.core.Options.info'
<autosummary>:None: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document 'pynance.opt.core.Options.quotetime'
writing additional files... (18 module code pages) _modules/index genindex py-modindex search
copying static files... done
copying extra files... done
dumping search index... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded, 28 warnings.

Build finished. The HTML pages are in build/html.
```

The thing is, all of these class methods (such as `pynance.opt.core.Options.exps`) show up in the output documentation, and under 'Methods' for the class page, they are clickable links. The only problem with the output is that the 'Next Topic' link disappears where it shouldn't.

Here's the way my `.rst` files are organized, using the example of `pynance.opt.core.Options.exps`. First, `index.rst` has:

```
.. toctree::
   opt
   ...
```

Then I have in the same directory `opt.rst` with the following contents:

```
.. automodule:: pynance.opt

.. toctree::

   opt.core
   ...
```

Then I have in the file `opt.core.rst`:

```
.. automodule:: pynance.opt.core

.. autoclass:: Options
   :members:
```

What am I doing wrong here? I want my class methods all to show up properly and the 'Next Topic' links to link through my whole package.

Comment: For complete context here is the current repo https://github.com/aisthesis/pynance/tree/nextversion/doc/source

Comment: Just discovered this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206334/sphinx-autosummary-toctree-contains-reference-to-nonexisting-document-warnings